# Trouble with booting from DVD on a Mac

Tags: mac, downloads, dvd

So I just downloaded the latest edition of Ubuntu 32 bit onto a blank DVD. I went through the whole disk terminal and set it up the way the website showed. However when I inserted the disk it said it wasn't compatible. I ignored this and restarted the computer anyway, like it says to do. The disk then ejected and it booted OSX.

I am running lion OS and it is a MacBook Pro if that is relevant. Can anybody tell me if this is because I downloaded a 32 bit and the computer might be a 64? I really don't know, as I am very new to all of this. Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: Can you tell us what processor you have?

Comment: It's a 2 ghz intel core i7